# How do I define ASP.NET MVC3 MIME Types? and JPlayer

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, video, mime-types, jplayer

Is there a way to define MIME Types in ASP.NET MVC3 while debugging? I read that you have to define them for the IIS 7 config. but I would like to know if the jplayer videos work if I somehow can define the MIME Types while debugging in IE9. The JPlayer videos work for me in all browsers except IE9.

Comment: How do you return a stream for a video? Is it an .ashx handler or just a direct path to your video? (By the way, I strongly recommend to deploy to a local IIS instance and remote-debug it when needed, so you can get Accept-Ranges header as well)

Comment: its just a direct path, it works for me when I publish the project to the IIS. However, while I'm debugging, it doest work. Im guessing that it works when I publish to the IIS because I defined the MIME Types in the IIS config. I just want to know if there is a way to make it work while debugging (this problem only happens in ie9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that was an .ashx handler (which I also recommend to use instead of direct paths, as it will allow you to perform some security checks) you would be able to add whatever headers you want to the Response object in code-behind. Otherwise, I think you can't take control of mime types or whatsoever. That was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924647/setting-mime-types-using-the-asp-net-development-server).

Comment: It could be a good idea to stop using cassini and just change the  config properties of the app to use the local IIS as its recomended in the post you linked.