# svg is not working on IIS webserver on localhost

Tags: asp.net, css, iis, svg

I'm trying to set a ".svg" image as background-image using css, but it is not working.  The url is valid and returns 200 status code and works on ".png" images.

What is the problem?

Comment: What's your IIS version?

Comment: check the Mime-Types setting allowed on your server.

Comment: i think its 7.5,
when i run the html page as a single page, it runs normally..
the problem is when running from the localhost

Comment: @Furqan, can u give me more info please? :)

Comment: should i change the web.config??

Comment: Mime-type represents the content that can be served by the server ans certain mime-types are not allowed by default on IIS. so assuming your are on IIS7, go to IIS administration (type Inetmgr on RUN), select the site from which you want to serve and select `MIME-Types` from the right hand pane, that shall give you the list of allowed Mime-Types, check `svg` in it or add it if not found.

Comment: @Furqan, thank you very much, but it seems that is had nothing to do with IIS.. could i edit the web.config adding the MIME types ??

Comment: @HasanAboShally, if it has nothing to do with IIS, it shall not help adding it in web.config, since web.config also achieves the same purpose.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Your IIS is most likely not configured with SVG as a content type, try adding

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
</staticContent>
```

inside the `<system.webServer>` scope of your web.config.

This will of course only work if your application is the one serving up the `svg`. If the `svg` is not contained inside your application but in a separate directory of the web server, you'll need to add the same mapping to your web server instead inside the "mime-types" tab.

Comment: If you are adding mime types into your application, it's good practise to remove the type you are adding first:

     <remove fileExtension=".extension" />
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".extension" mimeType="type/a" />

This avoids a conflict if the mime type is already configured on the web server you are deploying to. This sort of issue is common when deploying to different versions of IIS / IISExpress.

Comment: You sir, are a genius.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying with Drupal And None of the .svg icons are loading. Thanks for this config. It worked as expected!

Answer (score 29):

Try This - Your App/Website under Default Settings of IIS Manager

[image: Default Site Under IIS Manager]

Then "Add" -> `{ .svg : image/svg+xml }`

Comment: Worked on IIS 7.5 with an ASP.NET web app serving up local .SVG files. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

from web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

or in IIS
go to MIME Types and add file name extension:.svg
MIME Type: image/svg+xml

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I included all of the mime-types I wanted in the applicationHost.config file (which is usually located at C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config) under the `<system.webServer>` scope, like [Joachim Isaksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477878/joachim-isaksson) mentioned. This allows all of my IIS sites to inherit the same mime-types, and gives you one location to change them if something goes wrong.

Comment: This solved the issue for me.  I tried adding the mimeMap tag to my site's web.config, but it did not work.  I tried various other solutions like tweaking the svg file in notepad.  But this is the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, if anyone want to use IIS Manager for the same, select 'top node' on 'Connections' tree (typically the name of the machine you're on), and on right side, locate 'MIME Types' in 'IIS' section - double click the same. You should see list of all file types with 'Entry Type' as 'Local'. Add '.svg' type as mentioned by posts above (which amends same file as mentioned by 'Markaius'). This enables to 'inherit' same MIME type for any application on the machine.