# Angular svg image is not loading after deployment iis

Tags: angular, iis, production

I am using Angular 8 for development of an application. So after that i deployed my application through ng-build --prod. And i got the dist folder with all my file and pasted on server.

Everything is running fine but one image is not loading and it is present in the main root folder.[image]

I checked all things but this image is not loading even my files is also placed in correct path. 
[image]

I also check all permissions and also give Everyone group permission to allow full control but this error is not gone with that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an Angular issue.

Most probably your IIS is not configured for the SVG Mime Type.

Have a look at: [svg is not working on IIS webserver on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328651/svg-is-not-working-on-iis-webserver-on-localhost)
on how to configure it properly.

Comment: Hi kacase. Thank you for your answer and really helpfull because i spend two days to find where is the error. But thanks again.