# Video.js in modal stops playing back after initial modal close, on iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, video.js

On my site, I'm using Video.js to embed a movie in a Twitter Bootstrap modal. When I open the modal, the video should play, and when I close the modal the video should stop and return to the beginning.

This works fine the first time I load the page. But after I've closed the modal once, when I reopen it the video refuses to play. There are no JS errors. I'm testing using the iOS emulator with iWebInspector. When I put breakpoints in the modal open/close callbacks, my video.js object seems  perfectly normal, only the video doesn't respond to call to .play().

Comment: are you trying to play the video with JS command? or by clicking\tapping it?

Answer (score 0):

So I'll list off my experiences:

1.) I was running Video.JS + Twitter Bootstrap modal
2.) The videos were being hosted via Azure cloud storage

First, make sure your web server handles the mimeTypes; PARAMOUNT! [Setting MIME types using the ASP.NET Development Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924647/setting-mime-types-using-the-asp-net-development-server)

Next, if you are requesting the video, make sure the response contains a "range" value. Refer to this: [Sample http range request session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293687/sample-http-range-request-session)

Without a range value, the video player doesn't know when the video is supposed to end... so it'll never allow you to replay or go back to the beginning.