# SVG images are not display asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, svg, xhtml

I have images in a svg format. When i used it on a simple html it display, but when i try to use it in a real project (asp.net mvc 4, visual studio 2010) it doesn't display.

```
    @model KZStream.Web.Site.Models.IamSelling.IamSellingModel
@using KZStream.Web.Site.Resources.Views.Products
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Mobile.cshtml";
}
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="top-pannel">
        <div class="tp-languge">
            <a href="">Русский</a>
        </div>
        <div class="tp-basket">
        </div>
        <div class="tp-sign-in">
            <a href="">Войти</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <header>
        <div class="main-page-header clearfix">
            <div class="mp-logo">
                <img src="/Content/images/mobile/MS_Logo.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="mp-join-us">
                <button class="kzstreambutton button-orange">
                    <span>Присоединиться</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <div class="main-page-menu">
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="main-page-cont">
    </div>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: You src path is wrong

Comment: depending on you folder structure, try: src="../Content/images/mobile/MS_Logo.svg"

Comment: Why? If image in png format it works ok

Comment: oh then, here is the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476526/do-i-use-img-object-or-embed-for-svg-files

Comment: I think problem in used technology asp.net mvc 4

Comment: Checkout the MIME type support configured for SVG if you use IIS.

Answer (score 14):

Try accessing the .svg file directly like `localhost:port/content/images/mobile/MS_Logo.svg`.

If you are getting filetype not supported message, You can add it below in Web.config to make sure your server is capable of serving the `.svg` format

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 4):

ok guys i found something related to this question that worked for me. i found that the solution for big svg file is:

```
@Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/image.svg")))
```

in razor file there is another approach with html partial but unfortunately this trick is not working with big svg file.

hope this help..

Comment: you, my friend, are a hero. saved my butt!

Answer (score 2):

the best way to call svg files is this:

```
<object data='svg-test.svg' type='image/svg+xml' width='500' height='500' />
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget width=" " height=" " parameters. I fixed my problem with this issue

Answer (score 0):

Beside the web.config change. if you are using ASP.net also make sure you run your VS solution  in IIS , but not VS development server. for more information. please refer to this question. 
[Setting MIME types using the ASP.NET Development Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924647/setting-mime-types-using-the-asp-net-development-server)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to render the SVG images on Razor Markup is use IIS Server: Click on Project > Use IIS Express(Or your installed version that commonly is IIS7). Be sure if you have added the Myme Type added if this not working.