# SVG files in VS2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, svg

All of a sudden my SVG files don't get displayed properly when browsing my MVC 4 site. They work fine in other projects and the same project displays the images fine when hosted in IIS instead of ASP.NET Development Server. I tried adding the MIME using the code below but it didn't change anything. It feels like this literally happened over night. Really confusing.

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
</staticContent>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924647/setting-mime-types-using-the-asp-net-development-server

Comment: Didn't really understand what to do with the snippet of code that was presented but I took the first advice and installed the full version of IIS instead.

Comment: MIME types are hard coded for ASP.NET Deployment Server. The code snippet, is just a proof of this. Adding MIME types in your web.config won't affect the Deployment Server since it does not understand <system.webServer> tag itself. 
Bottom line: Use IIS

Comment: How is it possible that it worked as late as last week? And my other projects run without problems?

Comment: That is difficult to comment on but you can check this out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scicoria/archive/2011/10/06/additional-mime-types-in-visual-studio-2010-development-web-server.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way to call svg files is this:

```
<object data='svg-test.svg' type='image/svg+xml' width='500' height='500' />
```